# Bootstrap - why width of the fixed positioned div gets reduced?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, fixed

I am trying to design a responsive webpage using bootstrap. I have the following HTML structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="well"><!--Page content here--></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="well">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <!--Form elements here-->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want the `div.well` inside `div.col-lg-4` to be fixed positioned. So when I add `style="position:fixed;"` to the `div.well`, the default responsive width which it inherits from its parent (that is 33.33%) gets reduced and the form elements gets shrunk. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/jamesfinn/pen/zLoyv).

In the CSS Box Model, `fixed` positioning takes an element out of the normal flow, and if there are no other sibling elements, the parent container will collapse. In this case, the form inherits it's width from the parent, but when taken out of normal flow with `fixed` positioning, the `width` value of the parent does not cascade. But when I add a sibling element to illustrate my point, in this case a Bootstrap 'jumbotron' element, you will see that the parent `.col-lg-4 .col-sm-4` element is once again visible, but it settles in underneath it's `fixed` sibling who appears first in source order.

Hope that helps.